# Using Perl's Getopt::Long, how can I prevent the module from trying to match ambiguous option names?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I am using the [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt%3a%3aLong) module to process command line arguments.

The typical behavior of this module is we could pass `-f` instead of full name of the variable `--file`. At the same time if I have another command line variable `--find`, and if I supply only `-f` at the command prompt, it would return with an error:

```
Option f is ambiguous (file, find).
```

I was wondering how can we curb such ambiguous usage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @downvoter : This question is useful and clear.

Comment: Upvoters: the question [shows no research effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), it can be answered by reading the documentation alone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long#Configuring-Getopt::Long) documentation:

> **auto_abbrev**
>
> Allow option names to be abbreviated to uniqueness. Default is enabled
>   unless environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT has been set, in which
>   case auto_abbrev is disabled.

---

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_auto_abbrev);

my ( $file, $fish );

GetOptions( "file=s" => \$file, "fish=s" => \$fish );
```

And the tests:

```
$ perl test.pl -fi 24
Unknown option: fi

$ perl test.pl -fis 24
Unknown option: fis
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn this auto abbreviation feature off you'll have to configure Getopt::Long using

```
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_auto_abbrev) ;
```